# Searchkick parallel reindexing using "mode: :async" returns argument error

Tags: searchkick

Looking into parallel reindexing to improve performance, but when I run `MyModel.reindex(mode: :async)` in a console, as suggested in the docs (https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#parallel-reindexing), I get:
`ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :mode`

```
Ruby (3.1.2)
Gem versions:
Searchkick (4.6.3)
Elasticsearch (7.13.3)
Rails (6.1.6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Searchkick [v4.6.3](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/tree/v4.6.3) doesn't has the support for `mode: :async` option.

You might need to upgrade the searchkick version to at least [v5.0.1](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#501-2022-02-27), to use this option.

For full change log, please refer [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Ah yes. Will `async: true` achieve the same thing?

Comment: @Pseudo-Hippy Yes, this will do the job for you. You can find more details how to you this [here](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/tree/v4.6.3#parallel-reindexing).